# How to edit command lines in Intellij Terminal

Tags: intellij-idea, terminal

I have `set -o vi` in my `.bashrc` and it does get invoked. But `Escape` does not return to `command-mode` in the `Intellij` terminal.  I had already followed a `Jetbrains` post for changing `Switch Focus to Editor` *away* from `Escape`:

[image]

[image]

But that was not enough:  Hitting `escape` on the command line shown just puts in additional control characters:

[image]

So how can `vi edit mode` for the ocmmand line be made functional?  If not `vi` mode then what reasonable alternatives exist?

I am on `2020.2 Ultimate` on `macOS` . I do *not* have `set TERM=linux`

Comment: `I had already followed a Jetbrains post for changing Switch Focus to Editor away from Escape` I guess you mean the https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-210461#focus=Comments-27-3385860.0-0 issue. Please check solutions from https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-224611 and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-164775

Comment: @Andrey  The solution I used was to change the key binding to `Command-O`  as shown in the question. I am uncertain what the suggested fix is from the 2 issues you sent; one is from `2019.1.2` whereas I have latest 2020.2. The other is about `set TERM=linux` which I do not do.